# Sorting a JTable using RowSorter for Strings of Integers

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I hope the title isn't too terribly confusing. Basically, I have a JTable that lists a directory out with info like file/directory name, date, and size. When I click on the headers of the JTable, I want to sort the table by that column. The listener below works great for names and dates, but produces incorrect results for the size:

```
    fSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
    table.setRowSorter(fSorter);
    table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
              int columnIdx = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(event.getX());

              List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
              SortOrder order =  SortOrder.values()[fCountClicks % 2];
              sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIdx, order));
              fSorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
              ++fCountClicks;
        }
    });
```

Reason it doesn't work is that I have sizes such as 60 and 277284. This sort sees the "6" in the 60 and assumes it's greater than 277284 because it compares the "6" and the "2". Can someone suggest what I can do in this case? Am I supposed to create a custom sort or can I somehow indicate that this String is actually an Integer for it to figure it out? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer would be best found by reading an appropriate tutorial like [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: *"can I somehow indicate that this String is actually an Integer"* - Use an `Integer` in the actual `TableModel`

Comment: Your current approach is also adding sort keys, allowing the data be sorted by multiple keys, I'm assuming this is what you want

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have read that tutorial previously already, I'm just having trouble applying it to my program. I have 4 fields. 3 of them are strings and those sort great using my approach, but the 4th one is an integer and it's not sorting properly because of reasons listed in the original post.

Comment: Do you mean to add new sort keys each time?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not necessarily. I just want to user to be able to click on any of the 4 headers and sort by that column while rearranging all of the rows in the other columns appropriately as well.

Comment: So, my first thought would be to get it to work so it could sort a single column only and verify those results. I'd also verify that the table model is returning a `int` value for the specified column and the value from `getColumnClass` is a `Integer.class` or equivilent

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is already working for a single column. It's working for 3 out of the 4. The ones it works for is: names, dates (mm/dd/yyyy), type (File/Directory). It doesn't work for size (1234).

Comment: So it can sort the size by itself (single column)? You understand that by adding sort keys like you are, you basically generating groups, which are then sub-sorted?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It sorts it, but incorrectly (60 is considered greater than 123 because it compares the 6 and the 1 and stops further comparing then). Admittedly, I'm not sure I understand what the sub-sorted groups are that you are talking about.

Comment: Assuming that when you try and sort the size column (by itself), the values are not been sorted properly, then you need to verify that the `TableModel` is returning `int` values from `getValueAt` and not `String` values. You also need to verify that `getColumnClass` is returning `Integer.class` (or equivalent numerical class type)

Comment: When you use `fSorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);` the way you are, you are basically defining a series of grouped sorts, so all the values are first sorted on the first key, they are then sub-sorted on the second key so on and so fourth, which might mean that it's possible for 9 to appear before 1 because the name takes higher priority

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sure you're sick of my by now, but the trouble with my performing the checks on getValueAt and getColumnClass is that I don't have any of those used in my code... Where would I look for that in? I added a couple more lines of code in my initial post to illustrate how I have fSorter set up. Also, dataValues is a 2 dimensional Object array.

Comment: `table.getModel().getValueAt(...)`. Maybe consider adding a runnable example which demonstrates your problem